# Need Guidance - Setting up entity relations in Entity Framework Core in .NET 8.0

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to setup one-to-one relationship between two entities ie. Hotel-to-Address within EF Core in the `OnModelCreating()` method, but I get a build error on line #6 `.HasForeignKey(...)`

> Error CS1660: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type.

```
1   // One-to-One relationship between Hotel and Address entities.
2   modelBuilder.Entity<Hotel>(entity =>
3         {
4           entity.HasOne(a => a.Address)
5                 .WithOne()
6                 .HasForeignKey(fk => fk.HotelId)
7                 .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction)
8                 .HasConstraintName("FK_Hotel_Address");
9         });
```

Although the same works fine when I'm setting up one-to-many relationship with another entity, the super entity `Hotel` being common in both.

```
11   // One-to-Many relationship between Hotel and Contact entities.
12        modelBuilder.Entity<Hotel>(entity =>
13        {
14          entity.HasMany(c => c.Contacts)
15                .WithOne()
16                .HasForeignKey(fk => fk.HotelId)
17                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction)
18                .HasConstraintName("FK_Hotel_Contacts");
19        });
```

My domain entities look like this:

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
    public bool IsActive { get; set; } = true;
    public DateTime Created { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;
    public DateTime Updated { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;
    public Guid? UpdatedByUserId { get; set; }
}

public class Hotel : BaseEntity
{
    // Initialising navigation properties in constructor
    public Hotel()
    {
        Contacts = new HashSet<Contact>();
    }

    public required string Name { get; set; }
    public string? Title { get; set; }
    public bool HasRestaurant { get; set; } = false;

    // Foreign Keys

    // Navigation Properties
    public ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
    public Address? Address { get; set; }
}

public class Contact : BaseEntity
{
    public string? Label { get; set; }

    [RegularExpression(@"[+][0-9]", ErrorMessage = "Invalid contact number. Please use numeric values without empty spaces.")]
    [MaxLength(15, ErrorMessage = "Upto 15 characters allowed.")]
    public required string Number { get; set; }

    // Foreign Keys
    public Guid? HotelId { get; set; }
    public Guid? RestaurantId { get; set; }
}

public class Address : BaseEntity
{
    [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Max limit reached.")]
    public required string Line1 { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Max limit reached.")]
    public string? Line2 { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Max limit reached.")]
    public required string City { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Max limit reached.")]
    public required string State { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Max limit reached.")]
    public required string Country { get; set; }

    [RegularExpression(@"[0-9]", ErrorMessage = "Only numeric characters allowed.")]
    [MaxLength(10, ErrorMessage = "Max limit reached.")]
    public required string ZipCode { get; set; }

    // Foreign keys
    public Guid? HotelId { get; set; }
    public Guid? RestaurantId { get; set; }
}
```

Found no official links by Microsoft or others that could explain this error and workarounds that could resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's because in the one-to-one relationship between Hotel and Address, you need to explicitly specify which entity contains the foreign key, because it could be either side.

Also, your Address entity is missing the navigation property for the Hotel.

So, let's correct that first:

```
public class Address : BaseEntity
{
    [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Max limit reached.")]
    public required string Line1 { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Max limit reached.")]
    public string? Line2 { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Max limit reached.")]
    public required string City { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Max limit reached.")]
    public required string State { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Max limit reached.")]
    public required string Country { get; set; }

    [RegularExpression(@"[0-9]", ErrorMessage = "Only numeric characters allowed.")]
    [MaxLength(10, ErrorMessage = "Max limit reached.")]
    public required string ZipCode { get; set; }

    // Foreign keys
    public Guid? HotelId { get; set; }
    public Guid? RestaurantId { get; set; }

    // Navigation Properties
    public Hotel? Hotel { get; set; }    <-- Add this navigation property******
}
```

Then in your OnModelCreating(), specify the type you are configuring to explicitly tell EF Core which entity has the FK. Note I'm going to write this in the shorthand form without the curly braces:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Hotel>()
    .HasOne(x => x.Address)
    .WithOne(x => x.Hotel)
    .HasForeignKey<Address>(x => x.HotelId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
```

Note, you don't require this same configuration for your relationship between Hotel and Contact, as this is a one-to-many relationship, so it's clear the FK is defined from the 'many' entity to the 'one' entity:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Hotel>()
    .HasMany(x => x.Contacts)
    .WithOne(x => x.Hotel)
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.HotelId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
```